# Finding the probability of an $n$-th day being dry given independence and constant probability assumptions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

**Problem**

I am trying to solve the following question (3.34 from Paul Meyer's "Introductory probability and Statistics", 2nd ed.):

The following (somewhat simple-minded) weather forecasting is used by an amateur forecaster. Each day is classified as **"wet"** or **"dry"** and the probability that any given day is the same as the preceding one is assumed to be a constant $\boldsymbol{p}$ ($0<p<1$). Based on past records, it is supposed that January 1 has a probability of $\beta$ of being **"dry"**. Letting $\beta_n$ equal the probability that the $n$-th day of the year is **"dry"**, obtain an expression for $\beta_n$ in terms of $\beta$ and $p$. Also evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\beta_n$ and interpret your result.

(Hint: Express $\beta_n$ in terms of $\beta_{n-1}$.)

**My attempt of a solution**
So far I've managed to write an equation
$$P(\text{dry}\mid\text{Jan 2})=P(\text{dry}\mid\text{Jan 1}) \cdot p + P(\text{wet}\mid\text{Jan 1}) \cdot (1-p)$$
or
\begin{gather*}
\beta_2=\beta \cdot p +(1-\beta)\cdot (1-p)=2\beta p +1-\beta-p\\
=1-p+\beta(2p-1)=p+(2p-1)(\beta-1)
\end{gather*}
By the same logic, I can write $\beta_n=p+(2p-1)(\beta_{n-1}-1)$. But after that I stumbled. The answer at the back of the book is $\beta_n=\frac{1}{2}+(2p-1)^n(\beta - \frac{1}{2})$. I do not have a clue as to how to arrive at that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start from $P_0=\beta$. The recursive relationship is
$$\begin{aligned}P(D_n)&=P(D_n|D_{n-1})P(D_{n-1})+P(D_n|W_{n-1})P(W_{n-1})=\\
&=pP(D_{n-1})+(1-p)(1-P(D_{n-1}))\end{aligned}$$
If a limit exists, then for $n$ sufficiently large $P_n\approx P_{n-1}$ so
$$P_{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now observe:
$$\begin{aligned}
P_1&=\beta(2p-1)^\color{blue}{1}+(2p-1)^\color{red}{0}(1-p)\\
P_2&=\beta(2p-1)^\color{blue}{2}+(2p-1)^\color{red}{1}(1-p)+(2p-1)^\color{red}{0}(1-p)\\
P_3&=\beta(2p-1)^\color{blue}{3}+(2p-1)^\color{red}{2}(1-p)+(2p-1)^\color{red}{1}(1-p)+(2p-1)^\color{red}{0}(1-p)\\
&(...)
\end{aligned}$$
The pattern is clear:
$$\begin{aligned}P_n&=\beta(2p-1)^{n}+(1-p)\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}(2p-1)^{n-k}=\\
&=\beta(2p-1)^{n}+(1-p)(2p-1)^n\frac{(2p-1)^{-1}-(2p-1)^{-n-1}}{1-(2p-1)^{-1}}=\\
&=\beta(2p-1)^{n}+(1-p)(2p-1)^n\frac{1-(2p-1)^{-n}}{2(p-1)}=\\
&=\beta(2p-1)^{n}-\frac{(2p-1)^{n}-1}{2}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I recoginize that the last term is the geometric series, where r=2p-1, |2p-1|<1, with indices running from 0 to n-1.  Can we write then $P_n=\beta(2p-1)^n +(1-p)\cdot  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(2p-1)^i$?

Comment: @ProwlersProfit yes it's a legit change of indices